# How to get the all keys type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Here is the problem, I declare a type A which is an object of specific type value.

```js
type A = {
    [key: string]: {
        value: any;
        validate: string;
        error: null | string;
        required?: boolean;
    };
};
```

I declare a variable without using this type

```js
let b = {
    name:{value:"", error:null, validate:"required"},
    email:{value:"", error:null, validate:"required"}
}
```

Then I simply get the all keys type of the object `b`

```js
type B = (keyof typeof b) // gives type "name" | "email"
```

Then I get all the keys automatically. Like this

```js
type D = {
    [key in B]: {
        value: any;
        validate: string;
        error: null | string;
        required?: boolean;
    };
};
```

If I Declare variable `b` with the type `A` then

```js
let b:A = {
    name:{value:"", error:null, validate:"required"},
    email:{value:"", error:null, validate:"required"}
} 

type B = (keyof typeof b) // gives type string | number
```

I want to assign variable `b` with type `A` and get all the keys so that I can use them in the `D` type.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: No. I want the keys of an already typed object or something like that.

Comment: Is `type B = (typeof b)[(keyof typeof b)]` what you are looking for ?

Comment: @SoumenKhara The question I linked has almost the exact same problem you described: You have a variable. You want to give it **both** the type `A` **and** still extract type information from it but you noticed that you can only have one or the other. Read the answer of the post for a solution to this problem.